# Python - Remove rows from CSV files based on column criteria

Tags: python, csv

I need to return ONLY first of each 'status' every time the status changes.  Here is an excerpt, for example from this data set I would only need rows 1,2,5,6,8,10,11,12,13,15,18,19,21.

```
Row,Serial Number,Time,Status 
1,1400004,3/10/2014 11:52,GREEN 
2,1400004,3/15/2014 11:45,YELLOW 
3,1400004,3/29/2014 7:59,YELLOW 
4,1400004,4/16/2014 15:59,YELLOW 
5,1400004,5/10/2014 8:18,GREEN 
6,1400004,5/11/2014 15:28,YELLOW 
7,1400004,5/24/2014 7:56,YELLOW 
8,1400004,5/26/2014 7:59,GREEN 
9,1400004,5/28/2014 8:26,GREEN 
10,1400004,6/13/2014 17:29,YELLOW 
11,1400004,6/15/2014 15:12,GREEN 
12,1400004,6/17/2014 8:57,YELLOW 
13,1400007,1/3/2014  11:55,GREEN 
14,1400007,1/18/2014 5:35,GREEN 
15,1400007,1/18/2014 18:32,YELLOW 
16,1400007,1/19/2014 21:50,YELLOW 
17,1400007,1/21/2014 10:56,YELLOW 
18,1400007,1/27/2014 8:15,GREEN 
19,1400007,2/6/2014  9:47,YELLOW 
20,1400007,2/12/2014 12:44,YELLOW 
21,1400007,2/18/2014 12:40,GREEN 
22,1400007,2/24/2014 12:08,YELLOW
```

Here is my code, I'm close but its off a bit.

```
import csv
with open('NEW2.csv', 'rb') as f:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f)
    entries = []
    for x in csv_input:
        if x[3] == csv_input.next()[3]:
            pass
        else:
            entries.append(x)
    print entries
```

Comment: Are those lines tab-separated?

Comment: CSV file, comma separated

Comment: Where are the commas? Please show us the real file

Comment: Based on your edit, I'd say you have tab separated file... which falls under the csv standard

Comment: Example:
1,1400004,3/10/2014 11:52,GREEN 
2,1400004,3/15/2014 11:45,YELLOW 
3,1400004,3/29/2014 7:59,YELLOW

Comment: Please ensure that your post contains the actual file format. Formatting in the comments is terrible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.  Keep a flag previous and update it to the most recently found line.  If the current status is not the same as the previous, add it to entries

```
with open('so_data.txt', 'r') as f:
        prev= None
        f.readline() #skip the first line
        entries = []
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            curStat = line.split()[-1]
            if not prev or curStat != prev:
                entries.append(i+1)
                #entries.append(line) #for the line instead of the line number 
                prev = curStat
    print entries
```

Comment: Using the 'previous flag' approach I was able to retrieve what I needed. @GarrettR

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

```
import csv
import itertools
import operator

answer = []
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for k, group in itertools.groupby(operator.itemgetter(4), csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')):
        answer.append(next(group))

for row in answer: print '\t'.join(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use 'pandas' for this task.
We just have to add another column: "prev_status" and print only those rows where: previos_status != current_status...

```
import pandas as pd

def strip(text):
    try:
        return text.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        return text

df = pd.read_csv(
        'status.csv', 
        index_col=['row'],                  # use "row" column as index
        parse_dates=['time'],               # parse time as date/time
        names=['row','serial_number','time','status'],  # let's define column names
        skiprows=1,                         # skip header row
        converters={'status': strip}        # get rid of trailing whitespaces
)

# let's create a new column [prev_status]
# and fill it with the "previos" status
df['prev_status'] = df.status.shift(1)

#print(df)
print(df.ix[(df['status'] != df['prev_status'])])
```

I used "strip" converter, because there were trailing whitespaces in the provided CSV. So if you don't have trailing whitespaces in your CSV file you don't need "converters" parameter and you can remove "strip" function.

Output:

```
     serial_number                time  status prev_status
row
1          1400004 2014-03-10 11:52:00   GREEN         NaN
2          1400004 2014-03-15 11:45:00  YELLOW       GREEN
5          1400004 2014-05-10 08:18:00   GREEN      YELLOW
6          1400004 2014-05-11 15:28:00  YELLOW       GREEN
8          1400004 2014-05-26 07:59:00   GREEN      YELLOW
10         1400004 2014-06-13 17:29:00  YELLOW       GREEN
11         1400004 2014-06-15 15:12:00   GREEN      YELLOW
12         1400004 2014-06-17 08:57:00  YELLOW       GREEN
13         1400007 2014-01-03 11:55:00   GREEN      YELLOW
15         1400007 2014-01-18 18:32:00  YELLOW       GREEN
18         1400007 2014-01-27 08:15:00   GREEN      YELLOW
19         1400007 2014-02-06 09:47:00  YELLOW       GREEN
21         1400007 2014-02-18 12:40:00   GREEN      YELLOW
22         1400007 2014-02-24 12:08:00  YELLOW       GREEN
```